# Unable to write to a writeable samba share

Tags: samba

I am running the latest stable samba 4.6.4 on a Ubuntu 17.04 server, and although I have my `[homes]` shares set to `read only = no` and `writeable = yes` (and SElinux is disabled) I am unable to have the logged in user perform write operations. What am I missing?

Here's my smb.conf:

```
[global]

   log level = 3 passdb:5  auth:10 winbind:2
   workgroup = ARW
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   wins support = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   # panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no

   read only = no
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
    valid users = %S
    path = /srv/samba/users/%S
    writeable = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
```

any help is greatly appreciated.  I can post more info if needed.

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: grrr. I figured out my own answer :'(

Comment: Good! Feel free to post an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay the answer is rather stupid. I had not cleared the /var/lib/samba caches and the local user database, which was out of sync and did not map primary group to 'Domain Users'.

So the real reason I ran into this problem is a mismatch in credentials between the tdbsam and Domain Users mapping to the user's group id.